# The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FilterScreen(dirty, dependencies:

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

---

> **The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FilterScreen(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedTheme,
> _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#899ff]], state: _FilterScreenState#3b894): Closure call with mismatched arguments: function '_FilterScreenState.build.' Receiver:
> Closure: (dynamic) => Null Tried calling:
> _FilterScreenState.build.() Found: _FilterScreenState.build.(dynamic) => Null**

---

```
 import '../widgets/main-drawer.dart';
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FilterScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/filters';

  @override
  State<FilterScreen> createState() => _FilterScreenState();
}

class _FilterScreenState extends State<FilterScreen> {
  bool _gluttenFree = false;
  bool _lactosFree = false;
  bool _vegan = false;
  bool _vegetarian = false;

  Widget buildSwitchListTile(String title, String description, bool curentvalue,
      Function updateValue) {
    return SwitchListTile(
      title: Text(title),
      value: curentvalue,
      onChanged: updateValue(),
      subtitle: Text(description),
    );
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('filter screen'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Text("adjust your meal selection ",
                style: Theme
                    .of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .titleMedium),
          ),
          Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                children: [
                  buildSwitchListTile(
                    'gluiten_free', 'only include gluden-free_meals', _gluttenFree,
                        (newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        _gluttenFree = newValue;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  buildSwitchListTile(
                    '_lactosFree_free', 'only includel lacost-free_meals', _lactosFree,
                        (newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        _lactosFree= newValue;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  buildSwitchListTile(
                    '_vegan_free', 'only include vegen_free_meals', _vegan,
                        (newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        _vegan = newValue;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  buildSwitchListTile(
                    '_vegetarian_free', 'only include _vegetarian-free_meals', _vegetarian,
                        (newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        _vegetarian = newValue;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      drawer: MainDrawer(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: where are you getting this error

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change `onChanged: updateValue(),` to  `onChanged: updateValue,`

Using `onChanged: updateValue()` call setState during build time. you need to trigger this method when you interact with `SwitchListTile`

For next error change the function like

```dart
  Widget buildSwitchListTile(String title, String description, bool curentvalue,
      Function(bool) updateValue) {
```

Full snippet

```dart
class FilterScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/filters';

 const  FilterScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FilterScreen> createState() => _FilterScreenState();
}

class _FilterScreenState extends State<FilterScreen> {
  bool _gluttenFree = false;
  bool _lactosFree = false;
  bool _vegan = false;
  bool _vegetarian = false;

  Widget buildSwitchListTile(String title, String description, bool curentvalue,
      Function(bool) updateValue) {
    return SwitchListTile(
      title: Text(title),
      value: curentvalue,
      onChanged: updateValue,
      subtitle: Text(description),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('filter screen'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Text("adjust your meal selection ",
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                buildSwitchListTile(
                  'gluiten_free',
                  'only include gluden-free_meals',
                  _gluttenFree,
                  (newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      _gluttenFree = newValue;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                buildSwitchListTile(
                  '_lactosFree_free',
                  'only includel lacost-free_meals',
                  _lactosFree,
                  (newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      _lactosFree = newValue;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                buildSwitchListTile(
                  '_vegan_free',
                  'only include vegen_free_meals',
                  _vegan,
                  (newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      _vegan = newValue;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                buildSwitchListTile(
                  '_vegetarian_free',
                  'only include _vegetarian-free_meals',
                  _vegetarian,
                  (newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      _vegetarian = newValue;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this what he tell me when i  change updateValue(),to updateValue                                        
      The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(bool)?'.

Comment: Change to `Function(bool) updateValue`